# When do I need the `using` statement for Disposable elements?

Tags: c#, dispose

I know in the below case, `using` does its job to release the disposable element, i.e.

```
using (StreamReader sr = StreamReader(filename)) 
{
    txt = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However, does the same happen if I use it inline? As you see, there I don't define it as a variable:

```
 txt = (StreamReader(filename)).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Because than it won't be disposed :)

Comment: Its very hard to understand what you are asking.  Without the keyword `using` you are not ever going to get something that calls `Dispose()` when the scope ends

Comment: It's not the same because in one you're using the `using` keyword and in the other you are not.  Your code examples are not equivalent.

Comment: Whether or not you define a variable doesn't affect whether the object needs to be disposed. It still got instantiated, and it still implements IDisposable.

Comment: Side-note, you can just use `File.ReadAllText` instead for this particular case.

Comment: Sure, I thought that might be the case.

Comment: @rokkerboci It'll *eventually* be cleaned up - the main problem with the second example is that you don't know exactly *when* it'll be cleaned up.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I know, but it's easier to explain like this :)

Comment: Does the second example even compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining or not defining a variable doesn't affect whether you need to dispose an object.

If an instance of an class which implements `IDisposable` is created, you should call `Dispose` on it when you're finished with it.

You can do that with `using` or manually calling `Dispose` - a `using` statement is usually more convenient and fool-proof.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the dispose method exists to allow the developer of the class (in this case `System.IO.StreamReader`) to release any unmanaged resources they may be holding on to (and a lot of people use it for general cleaning up).

As a rule, if a class implements `IDisposable` (and therefore contains a Dispose method) it should most definitely be called.

The `using` statement you have used above would be compiled into the following:

```
//Very roughly your code sample
using (var sr = new StreamReader())
{
    //Some code
}

//What gets spat out by the compiler
var sr = new StreamReader();
try
{
    //Some code
}
finally
{
    sr.Dispose();
}
```

As you can see, this pattern means that Dispose will be called regardless of whether the `//Some code` section throws an exception of not.

Essentially, it's a C# helper so that you don't have to write the *safe* code above to ensure disposal of disposable objects.

Because of the obvious benefits, the question should really be "When *shouldn't* you use using".

Comment: When the object you want to dispose isn't instantiated and disposed in the same scope... for example, if something that implements `IDisposable` is instantiated as a member variable of a class... then you _can't_ use it.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing does *not* happen in your second example as is happening in the first example. In your second example, the StreamReader will become **eligible** for garbage collection immediately after that line executes because you're not storing it in a variable (so it'll go out of scope). The key word here is "eligible" - there's no guarantee of when the object will actually be cleaned up. So the second line of code will result in a lock on the file being "held" until the garbage collector gets around to garbage collecting the StreamReader.

On the other hand, if you call `Dispose()` on the `StreamReader`, it'll release the lock on the file immediately without waiting for the garbage collector.