# Will an anonymous StreamReader close automatically?

Tags: c#, filestream

I've found the following code in a project I'm working on and I'm curious to know if it can be written more succinctly.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(CustomSettingsFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Firstly, what's the benefit of using FileStream? I understand that StreamReader can take a file path directly.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(CustomSettingsFile.FullName))
{
    var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Secondly, if I'm only using the reader once, can't I just anonymize it and omit the using?

```
var data = new StreamReader(CustomSettingsFile.FullName).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: `using` is the reason for auto-close. Without it you have to call `Close()`. I prefer `using`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I need the \`using\` statement for Disposable elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530556/when-do-i-need-the-using-statement-for-disposable-elements)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0

Comment: The suggested similar question does answer the main point of my question, but Guru Stron's answer also addresses my question about succinctness, so I think that answer is worth keeping. Perhaps my question would be more valuable to future readers with a different title. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious to know if it can be written more succinctly.

You can use [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0) or [File.ReadAllTextAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync?view=net-7.0) methods instead.

They create and dispose StreamReader [under the hood](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L833).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm curious to know if it can be written more succinctly.

First thing you can do in this specific case is to omit extra curly braces:

```cs
using (var stream = new FileStream(CustomSettingsFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

> Firstly, what's the benefit of using FileStream? I understand that StreamReader can take a file path directly.

Based on [the current implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamReader.cs,228) none, except for explicitly specifying the `FileMode` and `FileAccess`, though as far as I can see `StreamReader` will use the same defaults.

> Secondly, if I'm only using the reader once, can't I just anonymize it and omit the using?

No. You need to deterministically free the unmanaged resources when you have finished using them. General rule of thumb: If something implements `IDisposable` then it should be disposed (for example via `using` which handles exceptions).

Note that since C# 8.0 you can leverage [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) in some cases, which will call dispose at the end of current scope:

```cs
using var reader = new StreamReader(CustomSettingsFile.FullName);
var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Also in case when you don't actually need streaming (i.e. you need the whole data at a time) consider using [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0) which will do all the work for you.

Read also:

- [Cleaning up unmanaged resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged)
- [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)